# How do I store this array in a foreach loop?

Tags: php, foreach, array-push

I need to store an array in this format

```
array(2)
{
    [1002] => array(2)
    {
        [0] => string(1) "2"
        [1] => string(1) "1"
    }
}
```

So far i only have this:

```
function permissions($conn){
    $sql="SELECT PROCESS,PERMISSION FROM table WHERE PROCESS=1002";
    $result = $conn->executeSQL($sql);
    $return = array(); 
      foreach($result as $value){
        array_push($return,$value['PROCESS_ID'],$value['PERMISSION_ID']);     
    }
```

which brings:
I don´t know how to make this array multidimensional, i don't want the "1002" to repeat

```
array(2)
{
    [0] => string(4) "1002"
    [1] => string(1) "2"
    [2] => string(4) "1002"
    [3] => string(1) "1"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi try something like this:

```
function permissions($conn){
$sql="SELECT PROCESS,PERMISSION FROM table WHERE PROCESS=1002";
$result = $conn->executeSQL($sql);
$return = array(); 
  foreach($result as $value){
    if(!isset($return[$value['PROCESS_ID']])){
      $return[$value['PROCESS_ID']] = [];
    }
    
    $return[$value['PROCESS_ID']][] = $value['PERMISSION_ID'];     
}
```